# How to make an interoperable "push" based web service?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, interop

We've come across a problem where we have some data, lets say a stock price for example sake, and we want to provide a service that notifies clients when the price changes by a significant amount.

We need this service to be interoperable with as many clients as possible, across platform boundaries. Standards-based therefore seems a good way to go.

Asking clients to poll our service seems crazy, and a recipe for quickly overwhelming our server.

Is there a standards-based way to do pub-sub or some event based way of notifying clients of interesting events?

There is WS-Eventing, by it feels like there isn't wide framework support for it.

Comment: We're .NET but we want to open it up to clients across a range of platforms.

Comment: Which kind of client. Web-based or a program that you can install on the customer pc? Both ?

Comment: I recently looked for this myself and ended up using polling.  I could not find any stable, cross-platform, non-proprietary way to do this.  It amazes me that this has not been solved yet in 2011.

Comment: @keatch We want to expose an interoperable service i.e. we expect clients to use a diverse range of technologies, and we make no assumption about what kind of client application they may use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of others, I'd like to put out there the idea of using [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) to achieve this. XMPP (formerly Jabber) is an IETF standard which works somewhat like email to achieve push based instant messaging using an extensible XML based protocol. It also offer TLS for channel encryption and SASL for authentication. XMPP is also the basis of Google Talk. It is possible to run an XMPP server using open source software such as Jabber, and at a pinch its probably possible to use Google's Talk infrastructure to relay messages.

There are [XMPP libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) to simplify client and server development.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Comet, Ajax push, etc: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

That's specific to JavaScript but can work well with any type of asynchronous client.  The client "polls" the server.  The server then holds on to the connection until there is data.  The process then repeats itself.  You do have to take into account client timeouts, however.

Without having the client implement its own service, this is about the closest you'll come to a push mechanism.  I'm not sure if it's more costly to keep all these open connections or for the client to do true polling.  In general I would say the longer the period between each poll, the better traditional polling will perform.  Though if your servers can handle the extra connections, you'll have much less notification latency.

Comment: @saille: Since you have a variety of clients, maybe each of your methods should take a `maxWait` parameter.  The server always returns before `maxWait` expires, preventing client timeouts.  The clients can then decide what is optimal.  I would pad it some because of network latency and such.

Comment: Thanks, nice answer. Do you think this is a good solution in a B2B environment when the consumer of the service is likely to be a server? Also are we asking too much of the developers consuming the service? Got to think of the lowest common denominator.

Comment: @saille: I'll be honest I have never used it in this scenario, but I can't imagine why it would be problematic.  From the client's point of view, it works just like any other request, but it has some extra "lag".  I understand your concern, but I don't think passing in an extra integer is too complicated for a developer.  If it is, you could provide a simple version of the method that doesn't take the integer and returns immediately, but then you're back to polling.

Answer (score 1):

We could reverse the typical roles of service host and client. We would supply clients with a WSDL contract, and they would need to host a Basic Profile Web Service conforming to that contract. There would be a simple web services method that we, in the role of client, but provider of the service, would invoke to notify the customer of an interesting event.

Comment: Nice approach, and one I've used before. One of the problems is that your clients need to have an IP address that is directly reachable (NAT works, but requires more configuration). Another possible issue, depending on the requirements is that it generally excludes browser, mobile, and embedded applications. Browsers can't set up listen ports, and embedded/mobile devices generally don't have a directly addressable IP, and little/no ability to set up NAT.